# How to authenticate an http request that isn't POST?

Tags: http, rest, authentication

I'm creating a [RESTful api](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RESTful_API#RESTful_web_APIs), but I don't conceptually understand how to authenticate http requests that aren't POST.

For example, I should return a list of objects if I receive a GET request, but I only want to respond with that list if the request comes from somebody registered on my site.  With POST, I will get the username and pass with the request, but what about GET, DELETE, and PUT?

I'm using Django server-side and Java (Android) on the client side.  I might use [TastyPie](http://tastypieapi.org/), but I still need to authenticate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authorization is handled by the (aptly named) HTTP Authorization header.

The Authorization header contains the credentials/tokens/secret codes/etc., however attained, that the server can use to satisfy it's authentication and authorization requirements.

The Authorization head can be sent with any HTTP Request.

Feel free to look up HTTP BASIC or HTTP DIGEST authentication as examples of how the Authorization header can be used. Also consider looking at how Amazon Web Services uses the Authorization header for a more complicated example.

Comment: Thank you, Will.  I did a little reading and discovered that these concepts are encapsulated by the Tastypie framework.

Answer (score 0):

Make a POST request when user logs in for the first time and generate a session code for that user on server and send it to the browser. Now you can send that session code from browser by putting it in your GET query url every time you query and thus you can authenticate the user on server.

Comment: Or use cookies. But either way, the session code would be openly accessible to any network sniffer that can see the HTTP data, so make sure you are using HTTPS for any URL that sends that session code around. But even then, you still have to watch out for MITM attacks via HTTPS-aware proxies/debuggers, like Fiddler.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I'm familiar with Django's login and sessions functionality but, in my application, the client is not a web browser; it is a custom application on an Android device.

Answer (score 0):

`POST` is only required if your server uses Form-based authentication via an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` encoded HTTP request, instead of using HTTP-based authentication via the HTTP `Authorization` header.  `GET` requests can use HTTP-based authentication.

Answer (score 0):

authentication of an API call is not related to the HTTP method you use.

Think of your API's functional workflow in this way:

1. before you can send a regular API call, send a call to login / generate API login key
2. upon receiving an API call, immediately run an authentication check function to verify they're allowed to use that call.
3. if authenticated, continue. if not authenticated, die with some error code and message.
4. if continued, do normal function and finish.